# Retrieving duplicates from nested list

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider the following:

`data={{1,a},{10,a},{5,b},{4,c}};`

In my case duplicates are defined when for `{x1,y1}` and `{x2,y2}`, `y2` is equal `y1`. Hence in the case of `data`, I would get via `MyFunction[data]` the following result:

`{{1,a},{10,a}}`.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
Select[GatherBy[{{1, a}, {10, a}, {5, b}, {4, c}}, Last], Length[#] > 1 &]
```

seems to do what you want. Alternatives to this construction include:

```
DeleteCases[GatherBy[{{1, a}, {10, a}, {5, b}, {4, c}}, Last], {_List}]
```

and

```
DeleteCases[GatherBy[{{1, a}, {10, a}, {5, b}, {4, c}}, Last], {{__}}]
```

Answer (score 9):

`GatherBy` is usually fastest, but `Sow` and `Reap` are more flexible.  Here is a method using those.

```
data = {{5, "f"}, {10, "b"}, {10, "e"}, {6, "c"}, {3, "c"}, {6, "e"},
        {4, "a"}, {2, "c"}, {6, "f"}, {2, "g"}, {9, "e"}, {0, "d"},
        {10, "c"}, {6, "b"}, {6, "c"}};

Reap[Sow @@@ data, _, {#2,#}&][[2]] ~Cases~ {{_, __},_}
```

> ```
> {{{5, 6}, "f"},
>  {{10, 6}, "b"},
>  {{10, 6, 9}, "e"},
>  {{6, 3, 2, 10, 6}, "c"}}
> ```

As you can see, the output is in a somewhat different format, but one that IMHO may itself be useful.  You can recover your original output with `Thread`, e.g. `Thread /@` on the output above:

> ```
> {{{5, "f"}, {6, "f"}},
>  {{10, "b"}, {6, "b"}},
>  {{10, "e"}, {6, "e"}, {9, "e"}},
>  {{6, "c"}, {3, "c"}, {2, "c"}, {10, "c"}, {6, "c"}}}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Using some functions which were not availabe at the time the question was posed

```
list = {{1, a}, {10, a}, {5, b}, {4, c}};

f[x : {{_, a_}, {_, a_}}] := Splice[x]
f[_] := Nothing

BlockMap[f, list, 2, 1]
```

{{1, a}, {10, a}}

Answer (score 2):

Using `Cases`:

```
data1 = {{1, a}, {10, a}, {5, b}, {4, c}};
data2 = {{1, a}, {10, a}, {5, b}, {4, c}, {7, c}};

Cases[#, {_, Alternatives @@ Keys[Select[CountsBy[#, Last], # > 1 &]]}] &@data1
(*{{1, a}, {10, a}}*)

Cases[#, {_, Alternatives @@ Keys[Select[CountsBy[#, Last], # > 1 &]]}] &@data2
(*{{1, a}, {10, a}, {4, c}, {7, c}}*)
```

Or using `Pick`, `GatherBy` and the third argument of `GroupBy`:

```
data3 = {{5, "f"}, {10, "b"}, {10, "e"}, {6, "c"}, {3, "c"}, {6, "e"}, {4, "a"},
        {2, "c"}, {6, "f"}, {2, "g"}, {9, "e"}, {0, "d"}, {10, "c"}, {6, "b"},
        {6, "c"}};

Pick[GatherBy[#, Last], Values[GroupBy[#, Last, Length[#] > 1 &]]] &@data3

(*{{{5, "f"}, {6, "f"}}, {{10, "b"}, {6, "b"}}, {{10, "e"}, {6, "e"}, {9, "e"}}, 
  {{6, "c"}, {3, "c"}, {2, "c"}, {10, "c"}, {6, "c"}}}*)
```